# Vue and Element Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element, element-ui

I have a complex object, for brevity the object is structured in this manner:

```
{
     Sample: [{
      Model: {
          Id: "1"
      },

      Collection: [{
          Id: "1"
      }]    
     }]
}
```

The data table renders the model data fine.  But, when trying to access the collection, the table doesn't output the data.

```
<template>
     <el-table :data="Sample" highlight-current-row :row-class-name="tableRow" stripe :default-sort="{ prop: 'Sample.Id, order: 'descending'}">
          <el-table-column type="expand">
               <el-row :gutter="20" v-for="property in Collection">
                    <el-col :span="24"><div>Id: {{ property.Id }}</div></el-col>
               </el-row>
          </el-table-column>
          <el-table-column prop="Model.Id" label="Id" width="300"></el-table-column>
     </el-table>
</template>
```

Does the data being binded to the table ignore the loop?  I'm able to access during the binding as a prop, the data is being sent over, but when the loop is added, the data doesn't output.

[Element-io](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table)
[Vue](https://vuejs.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why the loop is not work, because `Collection` is in the `Sample`. Your data structure is a `Sample` array, it contains an object.

[image: data structs]

So, you can fix the code to this:

`v-for="(property,index) in Sample[0].Collection"`